# Replacing NA/null values in arrow table in R across multiple numeric variables without converting to R dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, na, apache-arrow

I'm working with an extremely large dataset with roughly 2400 rows (representing participant information) and 950 columns worth of relevant information in an `arrow` table in R. This is after condensing roughly 2000 parquet files with 2-4k lines each into a queryable database.

Unfortunately, roughly 400 of the individuals in this database had `NA` values for my variables of interest, which is generating a lot of `NA` outputs for some of the summary variables.

Something like this in the `arrow` table and subsequent `dataframe`

```
temp <- COI_tag |> filter(flag1 == 0, flag2 == 0) |> group_by(participantID) |> summarise(across(COI_tag$schema$names[grepl("concept_|term_", COI_tag$schema$names)][COI_tag$schema$names[grepl("concept_|term_", COI_tag$schema$names)]  %in% c("clean_concept_tags","clean_terms") == FALSE],sum)) |> compute()

> temp$concept_1
[
  [
    0,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    1,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    ...
    null,
    0,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    1,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null
  ]
]

> unique(data.frame(temp$to_data_frame())$concept_1)
[1] NA  1  0  8
> length(data.frame(temp$to_data_frame())$concept_1)
[1] 4702
> sum(is.na(data.frame(temp$to_data_frame())$concept_1))
[1] 4657
```

Is there a way to replace the `null` or `NA` values in the `arrow` table prior to the sum and compute that doesn't require pulling the data directly into R first (as `replace_na` seems to want)?

I can't provide anything as a sample due to the size and sensitivity of the data, but here's a few of the things I've tried already and the associated errors:

```
> temp <- COI_tag |> filter(flag1 == 0, flag2 == 0) |> group_by(participantID) |> mutate_if(is.na, across(where(is.na), ~ coalesce(.x, 0))) |> summarise(across(COI_tag$schema$names[grepl("concept_|term_", COI_tag$schema$names)][COI_tag$schema$names[grepl("concept_|term_", COI_tag$schema$names)]  %in% c("clean_concept_tags","clean_terms") == FALSE],sum)) |> compute()
Error in `mutate_if()`:
! `.p` is invalid.
✖ `.p` should return a single logical.
ℹ `.p` returns a size 3368621 <logical> for column `participantID`.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred

> temp <- COI_tag |> filter(flag1 == 0, flag2 == 0) |> group_by(participantID) |> replace_na(0) |> summarise(across(COI_tag$schema$names[grepl("concept_|term_", COI_tag$schema$names)][COI_tag$schema$names[grepl("concept_|term_", COI_tag$schema$names)]  %in% c("clean_concept_tags","clean_terms") == FALSE],sum)) |> compute()
Error in `vec_size()`:
! `x` must be a vector, not a <arrow_dplyr_query> object.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

> temp <- COI_tag |> filter(flag1 == 0, flag2 == 0) |> group_by(participantID) |> mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~replace_na(.x, 0))) |> summarise(across(COI_tag$schema$names[grepl("concept_|term_", COI_tag$schema$names)][COI_tag$schema$names[grepl("concept_|term_", COI_tag$schema$names)]  %in% c("clean_concept_tags","clean_terms") == FALSE],sum)) |> compute()
Error: Expression replace_na(participantID, 0) not supported in Arrow
Call collect() first to pull data into R.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Invalid metadata$r 
2: Invalid metadata$r
```

Comment: `coalesce()` might be implemented? I forget

Comment: To help us understand your goals and constraints, can you say more about why you can't or don't want to pull the data into a data frame first?

Comment: I think I actually figured it out. About to post an answer.

Comment: And to answer your question @JonSpring, it just takes an incredibly long time to do so in base R/tidyverse relative to an arrow table. By an order of magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

So based on an old post in the `arrow` repo I hadn't used in a moment, I was able to figure it out: https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/38473

```
COI_tag |> 
  filter(!prior365_treatment_flag, !prior365_comparator_flag) |>
  select(where(is.numeric)) |> 
  group_by(participantID) |> 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ coalesce(.x, 0))) |> 
  summarise(across(COI_tag$schema$names[grepl("concept_|term_", COI_tag$schema$names)][COI_tag$schema$names[grepl("concept_|term_", COI_tag$schema$names)]  %in% c("clean_concept_tags","clean_terms") == FALSE],sum)) |> 
  compute()
```

By calling `select` with the criteria I needed first, I was able to mutate the `NA/null` values into 0's via the `coalesce()` call.

I am unsure how this works without a direct call to highlight `na` values but it does.

Comment: Thanks @Mark. Will be sure to structure it as such in the future.