# Replace any value in an Arrow Table with another value

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, apache-arrow, across

Similar to a previous post:
[Replacing NA/null values in arrow table in R across multiple numeric variables without converting to R dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77622974/replacing-na-nul-values-in-arrow-table-in-r-across-multiple-numeric-variables-wi?noredirect=1#comment136845633_77622974)

I'm looking to convert some values in an output `arrow` table (`frequency` below) to another value. However, this time, I wish to conditionally replace values from a range of columns from their frequency counts to binarized values of 0 or 1 to display whether the variable for a given column exists for that participant (again, without pulling it into R because the data is large).

However, I have not had much luck doing this within the `R/arrow` environment itself.

The selection is supposed to include all columns that begin with `"concepts_" or` "terms_"` (a little under 950 columns, which are integer data) but do **not** belong to a list of variables from another dataset (Demographics, which are mixes of strings and integers, and thus, either produce errors or would be incorrect to change).

This is the only code I have been able to generate to produce the `frequency` arrow table from which this is drawn, as all other calls to variations of `mutate`, `select`, and `across` have thrown errors or produced `NA` across the board:

```
frequency <-
COI_tag |>
filter(flag1 == 0, flag2 == 0) |>
select(where(is.numeric)) |>
group_by(participantID) |>
mutate(across(everything(), ~ coalesce(.x, 0))) |>
summarise(across(COI_tag$schema$names[grepl("concept_|term_", COI_tag$schema$names)][COI_tag$schema$names[grepl("concept_|term_", COI_tag$schema$names)]  %in% c("clean_terms","clean_concepts") == FALSE],sum)) |>
left_join(Demographics) |>
compute()
```

However, all my attempts to flip the values > 0 to a simple 1 have resulted in similar errors (including a `where` and several `selects` not pictured here):

```
binary <- frequency |>
mutate(across(COI_tag$schema$names[grepl("concept_|term_", COI_tag$schema$names)][COI_tag$schema$names[grepl("concept_|term_", COI_tag$schema$names)]  %in% c("clean_terms","clean_concepts") == FALSE] ~ replace(.x, .x > 0, 1)))
Error in `column_select()`:
! Formula shorthand must be wrapped in `where()`.

  # Bad
  data %>% select(... ~ replace(.x, .x > 0, 1))

  # Good
  data %>% select(where(... ~ replace(.x, .x > 0, 1)))
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
Warning messages:
1: Invalid metadata$r 
2: Invalid metadata$r 

binary <- frequency |>
mutate(across(COI_tag$schema$names[grepl("concept_|term_", COI_tag$schema$names)][COI_tag$schema$names[grepl("concept_|term_", COI_tag$schema$names)]  %in% c("clean_terms","clean_concepts") == FALSE] ~ replace((.), (.) > 0, 1)))
Error in `column_select()`:
! Formula shorthand must be wrapped in `where()`.

  # Bad
  data %>% select(... ~ replace((.), (.) > 0, 1))

  # Good
  data %>% select(where(... ~ replace((.), (.) > 0, 1)))
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
Warning messages:
1: Invalid metadata$r
2: Invalid metadata$r 

frequency |>
mutate(across(COI_tag$schema$names[grepl("concept_|term_", COI_tag$schema$names)][COI_tag$schema$names[grepl("concept_|term_", COI_tag$schema$names)]  %in% c("clean_terms","clean_concepts") == FALSE] ~ replace(.x, .x > 0, 1)))
Error in `column_select()`:
! Formula shorthand must be wrapped in `where()`.

  # Bad
  data %>% select(... ~ replace(.x, .x > 0, 1))

  # Good
  data %>% select(where(... ~ replace(.x, .x > 0, 1)))
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
Warning messages:
1: Invalid metadata$r 
2: Invalid metadata$r 

binary <- frequency |>
mutate(across(everything()), case_when(x. > 0 ~ 1, .x == 0 ~ .))
Error in map_lgl(args, ~inherits(., "Expression")) : 
  object 'x.' not found
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Invalid metadata$r 
2: Invalid metadata$r 

frequency |>
mutate(across(is.numeric, ~1 * (. != 0)))
Error: NotImplemented: Function 'multiply_checked' has no kernel matching input types (bool, bool)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Invalid metadata$r 
2: Invalid metadata$r

frequency |>
mutate(across(COI_tag$schema$names[grepl("concept_|term_", COI_tag$schema$names)][COI_tag$schema$names[grepl("concept_|term_", COI_tag$schema$names)]  %in% c("clean_terms","clean_concepts") == FALSE]), case_when(. > 0 ~ 1, .x == 0 ~ .))

frequency |>
mutate(across(COI_tag$schema$names[grepl("concept_|term_", COI_tag$schema$names)][COI_tag$schema$names[grepl("concept_|term_", COI_tag$schema$names)]  %in% c("clean_terms","clean_concepts") == FALSE]), ~ case_when(. > 0 ~ 1,. <= 0 ~ .))
Warning: In ~case_when(. > 0 ~ 1, . <= 0 ~ .) = ~case_when(. > 0 ~ 1, . <= 0 ~ .), only values of size one are recycled; pulling data into R
Error:
! Problem while computing `..2 = ~case_when(. > 0 ~ 1, . <= 0 ~ .)`.
✖ `..2` must be a vector, not a `formula` object.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
Warning messages:
1: Invalid metadata$r 
2: Invalid metadata$r 
3: Invalid metadata$r 
4: Invalid metadata$r
```

I have found several wonderful examples that appear to work well in base `R` and `tidyverse/dplyr`, but not on `arrow` tables like what I have here (which is what `frequency` is).

If you have any suggestions on what might be wrong with my call, I would greatly appreciate any and all feedback.

## Update

Have also tried the following, unfortunately also to no avail:

```
binary <-
  frequency |>
  mutate(across(COI_tag$schema$names[grepl("concept_|term_", COI_tag$schema$names)][COI_tag$schema$names[grepl("concept_|term_", COI_tag$schema$names)] %in% c("clean_terms","clean_concepts") == FALSE], ~as.integer(. > 0)), . = 1) |>
  compute()

binary <-
  frequency |>
  mutate(across(COI_tag$schema$names[grepl("concept_|term_", COI_tag$schema$names)][COI_tag$schema$names[grepl("concept_|term_", COI_tag$schema$names)] %in% c("clean_terms","clean_concepts") == FALSE], ~(. > 0)), . = 1) |>
  compute()

frequency |>
    mutate_at(
        vars(COI_tag$schema$names[grepl("concept_|term_", COI_tag$schema$names)][COI_tag$schema$names[grepl("concept_|term_", COI_tag$schema$names)] %in% c("clean_terms","clean_concepts") == FALSE]),
        funs(case_when(
            . > 0 ~ 1,
            TRUE ~ .
        ))
    ) |>
  compute()

binary <-
    frequency  |>
    mutate_at(.vars = vars(COI_tag$schema$names[grepl("concept_|term_", COI_tag$schema$names)][COI_tag$schema$names[grepl("concept_|term_", COI_tag$schema$names)] %in% c("clean_terms","clean_concepts") == FALSE]),
        .funs = funs(. = case_when(
          . > 0 ~ 1
        ))) |>
  compute()
```

Comment: While the question might be a little long (subjective), I think you're getting little traffic/commentary on this because we have no sample data. It's often possible to help in shorter questions without it, but this is a bit daunting to try to parse through.